# How to move a bootstrap button to a specific area

Tags: php, css

[current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yld0j.png)
I'm currently trying to get my button to move so it's over in the top right of the card header, but I can't figure out how to get it to move over there. Anyone have some advice on how I could do that?

This is what my code for this section looks like currently.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="emailsettings">
                    <div class="card h-100 text-center">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="bg-light py-4" style="margin-top:0;"><strong>Update Email Configuration</strong></h3>

                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 1%;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                                i
                            </button>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content position-fixed">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><Strong>Instructions</Strong></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>Host - Your host is what type of email your using, such as gmail, hotmail or outlook (Ex: smtp.gmail.com)</p>
                                            <p>Username - This is usually your email address</p>
                                            <p>Password - This is the password that you use to sign in to your email</p>
                                            <p>Port - When sending smtp emails, port 587 is usually used </p>
                                            <p>Sending Email From - This is the email your sending this from, the same as your username</p>
                                            <p>Email Alias - This is just your name</p>
                                            <p>Enable TLS - When you enable TLS it will activate a security protocol that will encrypt your email to ensure privacy</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body" style="padding-top:4em">
                            <form action="adminpanel.php" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateemailsettings">
                                <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="host" name="host" placeholder="Host" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="smtp_username" name="smtp_username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="port" name="port" placeholder="Port" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="from_email" name="from_email" placeholder="Sending Email From" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from_name" name="from_name" placeholder="Email Alias" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="enable_tls" class="larger-label">Enable TLS:</label>
                                        <br>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger-checkbox" id="enable_tls" name="enable_tls" placeholder="Enable TLS" required>
                                        <br><br>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Update</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to move the "i" button to the right hand corner, you need to

1. enclose the button with `<div>...</div>` tags
2. Set the alignment to right

So will be:

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:right;">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 1%;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">i</button>

</div>
```

and all the code will be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-sm-12" id="emailsettings">
                    <div class="card h-100 text-center">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="bg-light py-4" style="margin-top:0;"><strong>Update Email Configuration</strong></h3>
<div style="width:100%;text-align:right;">
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 1%;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                                i
                            </button>
</div>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content position-fixed">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><Strong>Instructions</Strong></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>Host - Your host is what type of email your using, such as gmail, hotmail or outlook (Ex: smtp.gmail.com)</p>
                                            <p>Username - This is usually your email address</p>
                                            <p>Password - This is the password that you use to sign in to your email</p>
                                            <p>Port - When sending smtp emails, port 587 is usually used </p>
                                            <p>Sending Email From - This is the email your sending this from, the same as your username</p>
                                            <p>Email Alias - This is just your name</p>
                                            <p>Enable TLS - When you enable TLS it will activate a security protocol that will encrypt your email to ensure privacy</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body" style="padding-top:4em">
                            <form action="adminpanel.php" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateemailsettings">
                                <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="host" name="host" placeholder="Host" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="smtp_username" name="smtp_username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="port" name="port" placeholder="Port" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="from_email" name="from_email" placeholder="Sending Email From" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from_name" name="from_name" placeholder="Email Alias" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="enable_tls" class="larger-label">Enable TLS:</label>
                                        <br>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="larger-checkbox" id="enable_tls" name="enable_tls" placeholder="Enable TLS" required>
                                        <br><br>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Update</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. I don't want to move the submit button, I want to move the i button - which is a pop-modal, to the top right of the card header it's in

Comment: See my slightly revised my answer (which now do what you want -- move the i button to the right).